# k-Connected Graphs with minimum degree $\ge n-3$

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple k-connected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and minimum degree $\delta$, prove that for $\delta \ge n-2$, $\delta=k$.
Also for $\delta = n-3$ find a graph with $k\lt \delta$.

For the first question, the minimum degree can be either $n-1$ or $n-2$.
For the first case $G$ will be the complete graph $K_n$, so $k$ will be $n-1$.
I have difficulty proving the case where $\delta =n-2$. Any hints for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think I got it.

I used Whitney's Theorem, which states that a graph $G$ is k-connected if and only if for every pair $(x,y)$ of different vertices, there are at least k vertex-independent $(x,y)$ paths in G.

So, if $\delta=n-2$, all $v \in V(G)$ have degree $d(v)=n-2$ or $d(v)=n-1$. We examine all possible pairs of vertices $(v,u)$.

- If $d(v)=d(u)=n-2$, then $\forall x \in V(G\setminus \{u,v\})$ there
  exists the path $P_x=(v,x,u)$, that is vertex independent, so $n-2$
  paths.
- If $d(v)=d(u)=n-1$, the paths $P_x$ still exists and in addition
  there exists the path of length $1$, $P=(v,u)$, so $n-1$ paths.
- If $d(v)=n-2, d(u)=n-1$ then $v \in N(u)$ so we consider all paths $P_x$
  for $x \in N(v)$ plus the path $P=(u,v)$.

So in all cases the vertex independent paths from $u$ to $v$ are $n-2$ or more, so the graph G is $(n-2)$-connected.

Now for the second question I thought maybe to consider the unconnected graph $K_2 \cup K_2$ with $\delta = 4-3 =1$ and $k=0 \lt 1$. Is this "cheating"?